# Linq Query Handling Null Values

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

```
From r In ReceiptLines
Where 
r.RECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE >= _reportStartDate 
And r.RECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE <= _reportEndDate
Let amount = r.QUANTITY * r.PRICE
Let discount = r.RECEIPTDISCOUNTs.Sum(Function(d) d.DISCOUNT) 
where discount > 0
Group By Department = r.ITEMSTYLE.ITEM.CATEGORY.DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTNAME
Into Sales = Sum(amount - discount), 
Average = Average(amount - discount), 
Count = Count()
```

I am fetching all departments and their sales, average, count from the ReceiptLine, Receipt, ReceiptDiscount tables. The problem i am facing is, if i remove where discount > 0, I am getting null exception. But if I include that, then I only get sales that has discount. 
How would I write query that bring all sales less discount (if it has one). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your code is VB.NET. I added that tag, if that is wrong you can correct that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common pitfall with LINQ2SQL.

The function `SUM` in SQL returns null if there are no items in the collection, but the signature of Enumerable.Sum() returns an int. This gives a runtime exception when the SQL query return null where the LINQ2SQL provider expects an integer.

The solution is to cast the result of the sum to a nullable integer and use GetValueOrDefault to convert the null-case to 0.

Replace

```
Let discount = r.RECEIPTDISCOUNTs.Sum(Function(d) d.DISCOUNT)
```

with

```
Let discount = CType(r.RECEIPTDISCOUNTs.Sum(Function(d) d.DISCOUNT), Integer?).GetValueOrDefault(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
...
Let amount = r.QUANTITY * r.PRICE
Let nDiscount = r.RECEIPTDISCOUNTs.Sum(Function(d) d.DISCOUNT) 
Let discount = IIf(nDiscount == Nothing, 0, nDiscount)
Group By Department = r.ITEMSTYLE.ITEM.CATEGORY.DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTNAME
...
```

Comment: I think Muthu's code looks like VB.NET and the ternary operator is pronounced `IF(Condition, TrueValue, FalseValue)` in VB.NET.

Comment: Yep! got used to code in c# for a long time. Haven't noticed that. thanks.

Comment: and... `null` is spelled `Nothing` in VB.NET. Writing VB.NET when you are used to c# feels like you have poured two cups of coffee in you keyboard. You just type along as usual, but you get red squiggles everywhere.